# How do I fix this random bug in svelte

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

Every time I try to run the application it gives me this error
[image]

It's also always on the first import type line no matter what it is or if I switch them all to normal imports then it would be on the first line of the class with the same message just pointing at a different line.

I've used this guide from svelte.dev to make the project

```
npx degit sveltejs/template svelte-typescript-app
cd svelte-typescript-app
node scripts/setupTypeScript.js
```

Edit: Everything works fine if I don't use that exact file

Comment: its a .ts file, shouldnt it be .js ?

Comment: I have TypeScript enabled and I want to use TypeScript so I think it should be .ts

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import it like

```
import type { SidebarInfo } from "../static/sidebar"

// Sidebar.ts
export type SidebarInfo = {}
```